# How to correctly redirect stdout, logging and tqdm into a PyQt widget

Tags: python, logging, pyqt, stdout, tqdm

### TL;DR

For answers, see:

1. my 2019 initially own accepted answer using a text edit and stdout/stderr streams redirections, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/55082521/7237062
2. my second answer, **now marked as the accepted one:** a derived and improved approach with a real  QProgressBar ! https://stackoverflow.com/a/74091829/7237062

### QUESTION

First of all, I know that a lot of questions are similar to this one.
But after spending so much time on it, I now look for help from the community.

I developed and use a bunch of python modules that rely on `tqdm`.
I want them to be usable inside Jupyter, in console or with a GUI.
Everything works fine in Jupyter or console : there are no collisions between logging/prints and tqdm progress bars. Here is a sample code that shows the console/Jupyter behavior:

```
# coding=utf-8
from tqdm.auto import tqdm
import time
import logging
import sys
import datetime
__is_setup_done = False


def setup_logging(log_prefix):
    global __is_setup_done

    if __is_setup_done:
        pass
    else:
        __log_file_name = "{}-{}_log_file.txt".format(log_prefix,
                                                      datetime.datetime.utcnow().isoformat().replace(":", "-"))

        __log_format = '%(asctime)s - %(name)-30s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s'
        __console_date_format = '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'
        __file_date_format = '%Y-%m-%d %H-%M-%S'

        root = logging.getLogger()
        root.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

        console_formatter = logging.Formatter(__log_format, __console_date_format)

        file_formatter = logging.Formatter(__log_format, __file_date_format)
        file_handler = logging.FileHandler(__log_file_name, mode='a', delay=True)
        # file_handler = TqdmLoggingHandler2(__log_file_name, mode='a', delay=True)
        file_handler.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
        file_handler.setFormatter(file_formatter)
        root.addHandler(file_handler)

        tqdm_handler = TqdmLoggingHandler()
        tqdm_handler.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
        tqdm_handler.setFormatter(console_formatter)
        root.addHandler(tqdm_handler)

        __is_setup_done = True

class TqdmLoggingHandler(logging.StreamHandler):

    def __init__(self, level=logging.NOTSET):
        logging.StreamHandler.__init__(self)

    def emit(self, record):
        msg = self.format(record)
        tqdm.write(msg)
        # from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38543506/change-logging-print-function-to-tqdm-write-so-logging-doesnt-interfere-wit/38739634#38739634
        self.flush()


def example_long_procedure():
    setup_logging('long_procedure')
    __logger = logging.getLogger('long_procedure')
    __logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
    for i in tqdm(range(10), unit_scale=True, dynamic_ncols=True, file=sys.stdout):
        time.sleep(.1)
        __logger.info('foo {}'.format(i))

example_long_procedure()
```

The obtained output:

```
2019-03-07 22:22:27 - long_procedure                 - INFO - foo 0
2019-03-07 22:22:27 - long_procedure                 - INFO - foo 1
2019-03-07 22:22:27 - long_procedure                 - INFO - foo 2
2019-03-07 22:22:27 - long_procedure                 - INFO - foo 3
2019-03-07 22:22:27 - long_procedure                 - INFO - foo 4
2019-03-07 22:22:28 - long_procedure                 - INFO - foo 5
2019-03-07 22:22:28 - long_procedure                 - INFO - foo 6
2019-03-07 22:22:28 - long_procedure                 - INFO - foo 7
2019-03-07 22:22:28 - long_procedure                 - INFO - foo 8
2019-03-07 22:22:28 - long_procedure                 - INFO - foo 9
100%|¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦| 10.0/10.0 [00:01<00:00, 9.69it/s]
```

Now, I'm making a GUI with PyQt that uses code similar to above. Since processing may be long, I used threading in order to avoid freezing HMI during processing. I also used `stdout` redirection using Queue() towards a Qt QWidget so the user can see what is happenning.

*My current use case is 1 single thread that has logs and tqdm progress bars to redirect to 1 dedicated widget. (I'm not looking for multiple threads to feed the widget with multiple logs and multiple tqdm progress bar).*

I managed to redirect stdout thanks to the informations from [Redirecting stdout and stderr to a PyQt5 QTextEdit from a secondary thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21071448/redirecting-stdout-and-stderr-to-a-pyqt4-qtextedit-from-a-secondary-thread).
However, only logger lines are redirected. TQDM progress bar is still directed to the console output.

Here is my current code:

```
# coding=utf-8

import time
import logging
import sys
import datetime
__is_setup_done = False

from queue import Queue

from PyQt5.QtCore import pyqtSlot, pyqtSignal, QObject, QThread, QMetaObject, Q_ARG, Qt
from PyQt5.QtGui import QTextCursor, QFont
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QTextEdit, QPlainTextEdit, QWidget, QToolButton, QVBoxLayout, QApplication
from tqdm.auto import tqdm


class MainApp(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        setup_logging(self.__class__.__name__)


        self.__logger = logging.getLogger(self.__class__.__name__)
        self.__logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

        # create console text queue
        self.queue_console_text = Queue()
        # redirect stdout to the queue
        output_stream = WriteStream(self.queue_console_text)
        sys.stdout = output_stream

        layout = QVBoxLayout()

        self.setMinimumWidth(500)

        # GO button
        self.btn_perform_actions = QToolButton(self)
        self.btn_perform_actions.setText('Launch long processing')
        self.btn_perform_actions.clicked.connect(self._btn_go_clicked)

        self.console_text_edit = ConsoleTextEdit(self)

        self.thread_initialize = QThread()
        self.init_procedure_object = InitializationProcedures(self)

        # create console text read thread + receiver object
        self.thread_queue_listener = QThread()
        self.console_text_receiver = ThreadConsoleTextQueueReceiver(self.queue_console_text)
        # connect receiver object to widget for text update
        self.console_text_receiver.queue_element_received_signal.connect(self.console_text_edit.append_text)
        # attach console text receiver to console text thread
        self.console_text_receiver.moveToThread(self.thread_queue_listener)
        # attach to start / stop methods
        self.thread_queue_listener.started.connect(self.console_text_receiver.run)
        self.thread_queue_listener.finished.connect(self.console_text_receiver.finished)
        self.thread_queue_listener.start()

        layout.addWidget(self.btn_perform_actions)
        layout.addWidget(self.console_text_edit)
        self.setLayout(layout)
        self.show()

    @pyqtSlot()
    def _btn_go_clicked(self):
        # prepare thread for long operation
        self.init_procedure_object.moveToThread(self.thread_initialize)
        self.thread_initialize.started.connect(self.init_procedure_object.run)
        self.thread_initialize.finished.connect(self.init_procedure_object.finished)
        # start thread
        self.btn_perform_actions.setEnabled(False)
        self.thread_initialize.start()


class WriteStream(object):
    def __init__(self, q: Queue):
        self.queue = q

    def write(self, text):
        """
        Redirection of stream to the given queue
        """
        self.queue.put(text)

    def flush(self):
        """
        Stream flush implementation
        """
        pass


class ThreadConsoleTextQueueReceiver(QObject):
    queue_element_received_signal = pyqtSignal(str)

    def __init__(self, q: Queue, *args, **kwargs):
        QObject.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.queue = q

    @pyqtSlot()
    def run(self):
        self.queue_element_received_signal.emit('---> Console text queue reception Started <---\n')
        while True:
            text = self.queue.get()
            self.queue_element_received_signal.emit(text)

    @pyqtSlot()
    def finished(self):
        self.queue_element_received_signal.emit('---> Console text queue reception Stopped <---\n')


class ConsoleTextEdit(QTextEdit):#QTextEdit):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super(ConsoleTextEdit, self).__init__()
        self.setParent(parent)
        self.setReadOnly(True)
        self.setLineWidth(50)
        self.setMinimumWidth(1200)
        self.setFont(QFont('Consolas', 11))
        self.flag = False

    @pyqtSlot(str)
    def append_text(self, text: str):
        self.moveCursor(QTextCursor.End)
        self.insertPlainText(text)

def long_procedure():
    setup_logging('long_procedure')
    __logger = logging.getLogger('long_procedure')
    __logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
    for i in tqdm(range(10), unit_scale=True, dynamic_ncols=True):
        time.sleep(.1)
        __logger.info('foo {}'.format(i))


class InitializationProcedures(QObject):
    def __init__(self, main_app: MainApp):
        super(InitializationProcedures, self).__init__()
        self._main_app = main_app

    @pyqtSlot()
    def run(self):
        long_procedure()

    @pyqtSlot()
    def finished(self):
        print("Thread finished !")  # might call main window to do some stuff with buttons
        self._main_app.btn_perform_actions.setEnabled(True)

def setup_logging(log_prefix):
    global __is_setup_done

    if __is_setup_done:
        pass
    else:
        __log_file_name = "{}-{}_log_file.txt".format(log_prefix,
                                                      datetime.datetime.utcnow().isoformat().replace(":", "-"))

        __log_format = '%(asctime)s - %(name)-30s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s'
        __console_date_format = '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'
        __file_date_format = '%Y-%m-%d %H-%M-%S'

        root = logging.getLogger()
        root.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

        console_formatter = logging.Formatter(__log_format, __console_date_format)

        file_formatter = logging.Formatter(__log_format, __file_date_format)
        file_handler = logging.FileHandler(__log_file_name, mode='a', delay=True)
        
        file_handler.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
        file_handler.setFormatter(file_formatter)
        root.addHandler(file_handler)

        tqdm_handler = TqdmLoggingHandler()
        tqdm_handler.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
        tqdm_handler.setFormatter(console_formatter)
        root.addHandler(tqdm_handler)

        __is_setup_done = True

class TqdmLoggingHandler(logging.StreamHandler):

    def __init__(self, level=logging.NOTSET):
        logging.StreamHandler.__init__(self)

    def emit(self, record):
        msg = self.format(record)
        tqdm.write(msg)
        # from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38543506/change-logging-print-function-to-tqdm-write-so-logging-doesnt-interfere-wit/38739634#38739634
        self.flush()

if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setStyle('Fusion')
    tqdm.ncols = 50
    ex = MainApp()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Gives:[image: Logging correctly redirected but not TQDM progress bar output]

I would like to obtain the exact behavior I would have had strictly invoking the code in console.
i.e. expected output in PyQt widget:

```
---> Console text queue reception Started <---
2019-03-07 19:42:19 - long_procedure                 - INFO - foo 0
2019-03-07 19:42:19 - long_procedure                 - INFO - foo 1
2019-03-07 19:42:19 - long_procedure                 - INFO - foo 2
2019-03-07 19:42:19 - long_procedure                 - INFO - foo 3
2019-03-07 19:42:19 - long_procedure                 - INFO - foo 4
2019-03-07 19:42:19 - long_procedure                 - INFO - foo 5
2019-03-07 19:42:20 - long_procedure                 - INFO - foo 6
2019-03-07 19:42:20 - long_procedure                 - INFO - foo 7
2019-03-07 19:42:20 - long_procedure                 - INFO - foo 8
2019-03-07 19:42:20 - long_procedure                 - INFO - foo 9

100%|################################| 10.0/10.0 [00:01<00:00, 9.16it/s]
```

---

Things I tried / explored with no success.

### Option 1

This solution [Display terminal output with tqdm in QPlainTextEdit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53381975/display-terminal-output-with-tqdm-in-qplaintextedit) does not give the expected results. It works well to redirect outputs containing only tqdm stuff.

The following code does not give the intended behavior, wether it is with QTextEdit or QPlainTextEdit. Only logger lines are redirected.

```
    # code from this answer
    # https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53381975/display-terminal-output-with-tqdm-in-qplaintextedit
    @pyqtSlot(str)
    def append_text(self, message: str):
        if not hasattr(self, "flag"):
            self.flag = False
        message = message.replace('\r', '').rstrip()
        if message:
            method = "replace_last_line" if self.flag else "append_text"
            QMetaObject.invokeMethod(self,
                                     method,
                                     Qt.QueuedConnection,
                                     Q_ARG(str, message))
            self.flag = True
        else:
            self.flag = False

    @pyqtSlot(str)
    def replace_last_line(self, text):
        cursor = self.textCursor()
        cursor.movePosition(QTextCursor.End)
        cursor.select(QTextCursor.BlockUnderCursor)
        cursor.removeSelectedText()
        cursor.insertBlock()
        self.setTextCursor(cursor)
        self.insertPlainText(text)
```

However, the above code + adding `file=sys.stdout` to the tqdm call changes the behavior: tqdm output is redirected to the Qt widget. But in the end, only one line is displayed, and it is either a logger line or a tqdm line (it looks like it depends on which Qt widget I derived).

In the end, changing all tqdm invocations used modules should not be the preferred option.

So the other approach I found is to redirect stderr in the same stream/queue stdout is redirected to. Since tqdm writes to stderr by default, this way all tqdm outputs are redirected to widget.

But I still can’t figure out obtaining the exact output I’m looking for.

*This question does not provide a clue on why behavior seems to differ between [QTextEdit vs QPlainTextEdit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17466046/qtextedit-vs-qplaintextedit)*

### Option 2

This question [Duplicate stdout, stderr in QTextEdit widget](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19855288/duplicate-stdout-stderr-in-qtextedit-widget) looks very similar to [Display terminal output with tqdm in QPlainTextEdit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53381975/display-terminal-output-with-tqdm-in-qplaintextedit) and does not answer to my exact problem described above.

### Option 3

Trying [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45722952/redirect-both-stdout-and-stderr-with-python-tqdm-library) using contextlib gave me an error due to no flush() method being defined. After fixing, I end up with only tqdm lines and no logger lines.

### Option 4

I also tried to intercept the \r character and implement a specific behavior, with not success.

Versions:

```
tqdm                      4.28.1
pyqt                      5.9.2
PyQt5                     5.12
PyQt5_sip                 4.19.14
Python                    3.7.2
```

Comment: I checked for tqdm project releases: latest is 4.31.1 but I do not see related differences with 4.28.1.

Comment: As explained in original post, it tried several things. All of them are inside code or commented out in the MCVE. I'll update the question with some hints on what code produces what output.

Comment: @eyllanesc I updated the question with more accurate description of the different attempts (code + output). I also added the expected output. The use case is 1 single thread that has logs and tqdm progress bars to redirect to 1 dedicated widget. (I'm not looking for multiple threads to feed the widget with multiple logs and multiple tqdm progress bar). I'll update the question with that particular information.

Comment: Question update accordingly. If needed, let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189620/discussion-between-lonewanderer-and-eyllanesc).

Comment: Reading your question again, you want the stdout and tqdm to be redirected to the GUI via logging, is my summary of what you want right?

Comment: Not exactly: I want the widget content to behave exactly as the console would have without redirecting to widget, i.e. the console behavior of the very first example I gave `example_long_procedure()`. So, widget receives the logging and tqdm, with tqdm always being the last line displayed/refreshed, and logging scrolling above the tqdm line if any (tqdm is always the last line in console and makes use of `\r`)

Comment: Okay, that gives more possibilities to solve.

Comment: I did some tests, and the best idea I've come up with is to somehow modify the behavior of the tqdm class so that when the class is instanciated (`__init__`), the default `file` parameter is set to an object of my choice (I guess it should realize the classical stream contract (`write, `flush`, `close`)). In my case it could be a WriteSream instance.

Comment: So, I'm trying to subclass the `tqdm` class and change the `self.fp` attribute in my constructor. I cannot find an elegant way to then make all `tqdm` class usage routed to the new class without breaking the mother class without reopening lots of code. But gang-banging class inheritance this way is tricky (I tried to change the tqdm class definition pointer to my own class, but I need the parent implementation to be in its original place !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Using QProgressBar

*Long after my inital anwser, I had to think about this again.
Don't ask why, but this time I managed to get it with a QProgressBar :)*

The trick (at least with TQDM 4.63.1 and higher), is that there is a property `format_dict` with almost everything necessary for a progress bar. *Maybe we already did have that before, but I missed it the first time ...*

Tested with:

```
tqdm=4.63.1
Qt=5.15.2; PyQt=5.15.6
coloredlogs=15.0.1
```

### EDIT: modified code working with multiple progress bars here

https://gist.github.com/LoneWanderer-GH/ec18189a8476adb463531a68430e94a8

[image]

```py
# This is derived from my own stackoverflow question and answer 
# Question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55050685/how-to-correctly-redirect-stdout-logging-and-tqdm-into-a-pyqt-widget
# Answer  : https://stackoverflow.com/a/74091829/7237062
#
# IMPROVEMENTS here:
# - captures up to 10 TQDM progress bars
#
# ------------- LICENSE -------------
#  Stack overflow content is supposed to be CC BY-SA 4.0 license: https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/
#  so this applies to the question and answer above

import contextlib
import logging
import sys
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod
from queue import Queue
from typing import Dict

from PyQt5 import QtTest
from PyQt5.QtCore import PYQT_VERSION_STR, pyqtSignal, pyqtSlot, QObject, Qt, QT_VERSION_STR, QThread
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QGridLayout, QPlainTextEdit, QProgressBar, QToolButton, QVBoxLayout, QWidget

__CONFIGURED = False


def setup_tqdm_pyqt():
    if not __CONFIGURED:
        tqdm_update_queue = Queue()
        perform_tqdm_pyqt_hack(tqdm_update_queue=tqdm_update_queue)
        return TQDMDataQueueReceiver(tqdm_update_queue)


def perform_tqdm_pyqt_hack(tqdm_update_queue: Queue):
    import tqdm
    # save original class into module
    tqdm.original_class = tqdm.std.tqdm
    parent = tqdm.std.tqdm

    class TQDMPatch(parent):
        """
        Derive from original class
        """

        def __init__(self, iterable=None, desc=None, total=None, leave=True, file=None,
                     ncols=None, mininterval=0.1, maxinterval=10.0, miniters=None,
                     ascii=None, disable=False, unit='it', unit_scale=False,
                     dynamic_ncols=False, smoothing=0.3, bar_format=None, initial=0,
                     position=None, postfix=None, unit_divisor=1000, write_bytes=None,
                     lock_args=None, nrows=None, colour=None, delay=0, gui=False,
                     **kwargs):
            print('TQDM Patch called')  # check it works
            self.tqdm_update_queue = tqdm_update_queue
            super(TQDMPatch, self).__init__(iterable, desc, total, leave,
                                            file,  # no change here
                                            ncols,
                                            mininterval, maxinterval,
                                            miniters, ascii, disable, unit,
                                            unit_scale,
                                            False,  # change param ?
                                            smoothing,
                                            bar_format, initial, position, postfix,
                                            unit_divisor, gui, **kwargs)
            self.tqdm_update_queue.put({"do_reset": True, "pos": self.pos or 0})

        # def update(self, n=1):
        #     super(TQDMPatch, self).update(n=n)
        #     custom stuff ?

        def refresh(self, nolock=False, lock_args=None):
            super(TQDMPatch, self).refresh(nolock=nolock, lock_args=lock_args)
            d = self.format_dict
            d["pos"] = self.pos
            self.tqdm_update_queue.put(d)

        def close(self):
            self.tqdm_update_queue.put({"close": True, "pos": self.pos})
            super(TQDMPatch, self).close()

    # change original class with the patched one, the original still exists
    tqdm.std.tqdm = TQDMPatch
    tqdm.tqdm = TQDMPatch  # may not be necessary
    # for tqdm.auto users, maybe some additional stuff is needed ?


class TQDMDataQueueReceiver(QObject):
    s_tqdm_object_received_signal = pyqtSignal(object)

    def __init__(self, q: Queue, *args, **kwargs):
        QObject.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.queue = q

    @pyqtSlot()
    def run(self):
        while True:
            o = self.queue.get()
            # noinspection PyUnresolvedReferences
            self.s_tqdm_object_received_signal.emit(o)


class QTQDMProgressBar(QProgressBar):
    def __init__(self, parent, pos: int, tqdm_signal: pyqtSignal):
        super(QTQDMProgressBar, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.setVisible(False)
        self.setMaximumHeight(15)
        self.setMinimumHeight(10)
        self.pos = pos
        # noinspection PyUnresolvedReferences
        tqdm_signal.connect(self.do_it)

    def do_it(self, e):
        if not isinstance(e, dict):
            return
        pos = e.get("pos", None)
        if pos != self.pos:
            return
        do_reset = e.get("do_reset", False)  # different from close, because we want visible=true
        initial = e.get("initial", 0)
        total = e.get("total", None)
        n = e.get("n", None)
        desc = e.get("prefix", None)
        text = e.get("text", None)
        do_close = e.get("close", False)  # different from do_reset, we want visible=false
        if do_reset:
            self.reset()
        if do_close:
            self.reset()
        self.setVisible(not do_close)
        if initial:
            self.setMinimum(initial)
        else:
            self.setMinimum(0)
        if total:
            self.setMaximum(total)
        else:
            self.setMaximum(0)
        if n:
            self.setValue(n)
        if desc:
            self.setFormat(f"{desc} %v/%m | %p %")
        elif text:
            self.setFormat(text)
        else:
            self.setFormat("%v/%m | %p")


def long_procedure(identifier: int, launch_count: int):
    # emulate late import of modules
    from tqdm.auto import tqdm
    from tqdm.contrib.logging import logging_redirect_tqdm
    __logger = logging.getLogger('long_procedure')
    __logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
    tqdm_object = tqdm(range(10), unit_scale=True, dynamic_ncols=True)
    tqdm_object.set_description(f"long_procedure [id {identifier}] Launch count: [{launch_count}]")
    with logging_redirect_tqdm():
        for i in tqdm_object:
            QtTest.QTest.qWait(1500)
            __logger.info(f'[id {identifier} | count{launch_count}] step {i}')


class QtLoggingHelper(ABC):
    @abstractmethod
    def transform(self, msg: str):
        raise NotImplementedError()


class QtLoggingBasic(QtLoggingHelper):
    def transform(self, msg: str):
        return msg


class QtLoggingColoredLogs(QtLoggingHelper):
    def __init__(self):
        # offensive programming: crash if necessary if import is not present
        pass

    def transform(self, msg: str):
        import coloredlogs.converter
        msg_html = coloredlogs.converter.convert(msg)
        return msg_html


class QTextEditLogger(logging.Handler, QObject):
    appendText = pyqtSignal(str)

    def __init__(self,
                 logger_: logging.Logger,
                 formatter: logging.Formatter,
                 text_widget: QPlainTextEdit,
                 # table_widget: QTableWidget,
                 parent: QWidget):
        super(QTextEditLogger, self).__init__()
        super(QObject, self).__init__(parent=parent)
        self.text_widget = text_widget
        self.text_widget.setReadOnly(True)
        # self.table_widget = table_widget
        try:
            self.helper = QtLoggingColoredLogs()
            self.appendText.connect(self.text_widget.appendHtml)
            logger_.info("Using QtLoggingColoredLogs")
        except ImportError:
            self.helper = QtLoggingBasic()
            self.appendText.connect(self.text_widget.appendPlainText)
            logger_.warning("Using QtLoggingBasic")
        # logTextBox = QTextEditLogger(self)
        # You can format what is printed to text box
        self.setFormatter(formatter)
        logger_.addHandler(self)
        # You can control the logging level
        self.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

    def emit(self, record: logging.LogRecord):
        msg = self.format(record)
        display_msg = self.helper.transform(msg=msg)
        self.appendText.emit(display_msg)
        # self.add_row(record)


class MainApp(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.__logger = logging.getLogger(self.__class__.__name__)
        self.__logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.setMinimumWidth(650)
        self.thread_tqdm_update_queue_listener = QThread()
        # must be done before any TQDM import
        self.tqdm_update_receiver = setup_tqdm_pyqt()
        self.tqdm_update_receiver.moveToThread(self.thread_tqdm_update_queue_listener)
        self.thread_tqdm_update_queue_listener.started.connect(self.tqdm_update_receiver.run)
        self.pb_dict: Dict[int, QTQDMProgressBar] = {}
        self.btn_dict: Dict[int, QToolButton] = {}
        self.worker_dict: Dict[int, LongProcedureWorker] = {}
        self.thread_dict: Dict[int, QThread] = {}
        for col_idx in range(10):
            pb = QTQDMProgressBar(self, pos=col_idx, tqdm_signal=self.tqdm_update_receiver.s_tqdm_object_received_signal)
            worker = LongProcedureWorker(self, identifier=col_idx)
            thread = QThread()
            thread.setObjectName(f"Thread {col_idx}")
            btn = QToolButton(self)
            btn.setText(f"Long processing {col_idx}")
            btn.clicked.connect(thread.start)
            worker.moveToThread(thread)
            thread.started.connect(worker.run)
            worker.started.connect(btn.setDisabled)
            worker.finished.connect(btn.setEnabled)
            worker.finished.connect(thread.quit)
            self.pb_dict[col_idx] = pb
            self.btn_dict[col_idx] = btn
            self.worker_dict[col_idx] = worker
            self.thread_dict[col_idx] = thread
        self.thread_tqdm_update_queue_listener.start()
        self.plain_text_edit_logger = QPlainTextEdit(self)
        LOG_FMT = "{thread:7d}-{threadName:10.10} | {asctime} | {levelname:10s} | {message}"
        try:
            import coloredlogs
            FORMATTER = coloredlogs.ColoredFormatter(fmt=LOG_FMT, style="{")
        except ImportError:
            FORMATTER = logging.Formatter(fmt=LOG_FMT, style="{")

        self.logging_ = QTextEditLogger(logger_=logging.getLogger(),  # root logger, to intercept every log of app
                                        formatter=FORMATTER,
                                        text_widget=self.plain_text_edit_logger,
                                        parent=self)

        self.widget_btns = QWidget(self)
        q_grid_layout = QGridLayout(self.widget_btns)
        self.widget_btns.setLayout(q_grid_layout)
        for idx in sorted(self.btn_dict.keys(), reverse=True):
            b = self.btn_dict[idx]
            j = int(idx % (len(self.btn_dict.values()) / 2))
            i = int(idx // (len(self.btn_dict.values()) / 2))
            q_grid_layout.addWidget(b, i, j)
        layout.addWidget(self.widget_btns)
        layout.addWidget(self.plain_text_edit_logger)
        for pb in self.pb_dict.values():
            layout.addWidget(pb)
        self.setLayout(layout)
        import tqdm
        self.__logger.info(f"tqdm {tqdm.__version__}")
        self.__logger.info(f"Qt={QT_VERSION_STR}; PyQt={PYQT_VERSION_STR}")
        with contextlib.suppress(ImportError):
            import coloredlogs
        self.__logger.info(f"coloredlogs {coloredlogs.__version__}")
        self.show()


class LongProcedureWorker(QObject):
    started = pyqtSignal(bool)
    finished = pyqtSignal(bool)

    def __init__(self, main_app: MainApp, identifier: int):
        super(LongProcedureWorker, self).__init__()
        self._main_app = main_app
        self.id = identifier
        self.launch_count = 0

    @pyqtSlot()
    def run(self):
        self.launch_count += 1
        self.started.emit(True)
        long_procedure(self.id, self.launch_count)
        self.finished.emit(True)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setStyle('Fusion')
    ex = MainApp()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

### 1. GIF showing the solution

[image]

### 2. How does it work?

As in my previous answer, we need:

- a queue
- a patched TQDM class
- a worker object to read queue and send signal to QProgressBar

New thing here are:

- a QProgressBar subclass
- we take advantage of the new TQDM context `with logging_redirect_tqdm():` which handles routing of logging traces
- use of a custom logging traces module, with compatibility with the coloredlogs module => provides a fancy QPlainTextEdit with logger coloredlogs :)
- no more tricks with stdout/stderr streams

Concerning the TQDM class patch, we redefine `__init__`, but now we also define `refresh` and `close` (instead of using the file stream trick from my previous answer)0

- `__init__` stores a new tqdm instance attribute, the queue and sends a "{do_reset:true}" (to reset the QProgressBar and make it visible)
- `refresh` adds to queue `format_dict` (it contains `n` and  total`)
- `close` adds to queue a string "close" (to hide the progress bar)

### 3. Full example (1 file)

```py
import contextlib
import logging
import sys
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod
from queue import Queue

from PyQt5 import QtTest
from PyQt5.QtCore import PYQT_VERSION_STR, pyqtSignal, pyqtSlot, QObject, Qt, QT_VERSION_STR, QThread
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QPlainTextEdit, QProgressBar, QToolButton, QVBoxLayout, QWidget


__CONFIGURED = False


def setup_streams_redirection(tqdm_nb_columns=None):
    if not __CONFIGURED:
        tqdm_update_queue = Queue()
        perform_tqdm_default_out_stream_hack(tqdm_update_queue=tqdm_update_queue, tqdm_nb_columns=tqdm_nb_columns)
        return TQDMDataQueueReceiver(tqdm_update_queue)


def perform_tqdm_default_out_stream_hack(tqdm_update_queue: Queue, tqdm_nb_columns=None):
    import tqdm
    # save original class into module
    tqdm.original_class = tqdm.std.tqdm
    parent = tqdm.std.tqdm

    class TQDMPatch(parent):
        """
        Derive from original class
        """

        def __init__(self, iterable=None, desc=None, total=None, leave=True, file=None,
                     ncols=None, mininterval=0.1, maxinterval=10.0, miniters=None,
                     ascii=None, disable=False, unit='it', unit_scale=False,
                     dynamic_ncols=False, smoothing=0.3, bar_format=None, initial=0,
                     position=None, postfix=None, unit_divisor=1000, write_bytes=None,
                     lock_args=None, nrows=None, colour=None, delay=0, gui=False,
                     **kwargs):
            print('TQDM Patch called')  # check it works
            self.tqdm_update_queue = tqdm_update_queue
            self.tqdm_update_queue.put({"do_reset": True})
            super(TQDMPatch, self).__init__(iterable, desc, total, leave,
                                            file,  # no change here
                                            ncols,
                                            mininterval, maxinterval,
                                            miniters, ascii, disable, unit,
                                            unit_scale,
                                            False,  # change param ?
                                            smoothing,
                                            bar_format, initial, position, postfix,
                                            unit_divisor, gui, **kwargs)

        # def update(self, n=1):
        #     super(TQDMPatch, self).update(n=n)
        #     custom stuff ?

        def refresh(self, nolock=False, lock_args=None):
            super(TQDMPatch, self).refresh(nolock=nolock, lock_args=lock_args)
            self.tqdm_update_queue.put(self.format_dict)

        def close(self):
            self.tqdm_update_queue.put({"close": True})
            super(TQDMPatch, self).close()

    # change original class with the patched one, the original still exists
    tqdm.std.tqdm = TQDMPatch
    tqdm.tqdm = TQDMPatch  # may not be necessary
    # for tqdm.auto users, maybe some additional stuff is needed


class TQDMDataQueueReceiver(QObject):
    s_tqdm_object_received_signal = pyqtSignal(object)

    def __init__(self, q: Queue, *args, **kwargs):
        QObject.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.queue = q

    @pyqtSlot()
    def run(self):
        while True:
            o = self.queue.get()
            # noinspection PyUnresolvedReferences
            self.s_tqdm_object_received_signal.emit(o)


class QTQDMProgressBar(QProgressBar):
    def __init__(self, parent, tqdm_signal: pyqtSignal):
        super(QTQDMProgressBar, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.setVisible(False)
        # noinspection PyUnresolvedReferences
        tqdm_signal.connect(self.do_it)

    def do_it(self, e):
        if not isinstance(e, dict):
            return
        do_reset = e.get("do_reset", False)  # different from close, because we want visible=true
        initial = e.get("initial", 0)
        total = e.get("total", None)
        n = e.get("n", None)
        desc = e.get("prefix", None)
        text = e.get("text", None)
        do_close = e.get("close", False)  # different from do_reset, we want visible=false
        if do_reset:
            self.reset()
        if do_close:
            self.reset()
        self.setVisible(not do_close)
        if initial:
            self.setMinimum(initial)
        else:
            self.setMinimum(0)
        if total:
            self.setMaximum(total)
        else:
            self.setMaximum(0)
        if n:
            self.setValue(n)
        if desc:
            self.setFormat(f"{desc} %v/%m | %p %")
        elif text:
            self.setFormat(text)
        else:
            self.setFormat("%v/%m | %p")


def long_procedure():
    # emulate late import of modules
    from tqdm.auto import tqdm # don't import before patch !
    __logger = logging.getLogger('long_procedure')
    __logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
    tqdm_object = tqdm(range(10), unit_scale=True, dynamic_ncols=True)
    tqdm_object.set_description("My progress bar description")
    from tqdm.contrib.logging import logging_redirect_tqdm # don't import before patch !
    with logging_redirect_tqdm():
        for i in tqdm_object:
            QtTest.QTest.qWait(200)
            __logger.info(f'foo {i}')


class QtLoggingHelper(ABC):
    @abstractmethod
    def transform(self, msg: str):
        raise NotImplementedError()


class QtLoggingBasic(QtLoggingHelper):
    def transform(self, msg: str):
        return msg


class QtLoggingColoredLogs(QtLoggingHelper):
    def __init__(self):
        # offensive programming: crash if necessary if import is not present
        pass

    def transform(self, msg: str):
        import coloredlogs.converter
        msg_html = coloredlogs.converter.convert(msg)
        return msg_html


class QTextEditLogger(logging.Handler, QObject):
    appendText = pyqtSignal(str)

    def __init__(self,
                 logger_: logging.Logger,
                 formatter: logging.Formatter,
                 text_widget: QPlainTextEdit,
                 # table_widget: QTableWidget,
                 parent: QWidget):
        super(QTextEditLogger, self).__init__()
        super(QObject, self).__init__(parent=parent)
        self.text_widget = text_widget
        self.text_widget.setReadOnly(True)
        # self.table_widget = table_widget
        try:
            self.helper = QtLoggingColoredLogs()
            self.appendText.connect(self.text_widget.appendHtml)
            logger_.info("Using QtLoggingColoredLogs")
        except ImportError:
            self.helper = QtLoggingBasic()
            self.appendText.connect(self.text_widget.appendPlainText)
            logger_.warning("Using QtLoggingBasic")
        # logTextBox = QTextEditLogger(self)
        # You can format what is printed to text box
        self.setFormatter(formatter)
        logger_.addHandler(self)
        # You can control the logging level
        self.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

    def emit(self, record: logging.LogRecord):
        msg = self.format(record)
        display_msg = self.helper.transform(msg=msg)
        self.appendText.emit(display_msg)
        # self.add_row(record)


class MainApp(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.__logger = logging.getLogger(self.__class__.__name__)
        self.__logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

        layout = QVBoxLayout()

        self.setMinimumWidth(500)

        self.btn_perform_actions = QToolButton(self)
        self.btn_perform_actions.setText('Launch long processing')
        self.btn_perform_actions.clicked.connect(self._btn_go_clicked)

        self.thread_initialize = QThread()
        self.init_procedure_object = LongProcedureWorker(self)

        self.thread_tqdm_update_queue_listener = QThread()
        # must be done before any TQDM import
        self.tqdm_update_receiver = setup_streams_redirection()
        self.tqdm_update_receiver.moveToThread(self.thread_tqdm_update_queue_listener)
        self.thread_tqdm_update_queue_listener.started.connect(self.tqdm_update_receiver.run)

        self.pb_tqdm = QTQDMProgressBar(self, tqdm_signal=self.tqdm_update_receiver.s_tqdm_object_received_signal)
        layout.addWidget(self.pb_tqdm)
        self.thread_tqdm_update_queue_listener.start()

        self.plain_text_edit_logger = QPlainTextEdit(self)
        LOG_FMT = "{asctime} | {levelname:10s} | {message}"
        try:
            import coloredlogs
            FORMATTER = coloredlogs.ColoredFormatter(fmt=LOG_FMT, style="{")
        except ImportError:
            FORMATTER = logging.Formatter(fmt=LOG_FMT, style="{")

        self.logging_ = QTextEditLogger(logger_=logging.getLogger(),  # root logger, to intercept every log of app
                                        formatter=FORMATTER,
                                        text_widget=self.plain_text_edit_logger,
                                        parent=self)
        layout.addWidget(self.plain_text_edit_logger)
        layout.addWidget(self.btn_perform_actions)
        self.setLayout(layout)
        import tqdm
        self.__logger.info(f"tqdm {tqdm.__version__}")
        self.__logger.info(f"Qt={QT_VERSION_STR}; PyQt={PYQT_VERSION_STR}")
        with contextlib.suppress(ImportError):
            import coloredlogs
            self.__logger.info(f"coloredlogs {coloredlogs.__version__}")
        # prepare thread for long operation
        self.init_procedure_object.moveToThread(self.thread_initialize)
        self.thread_initialize.started.connect(self.init_procedure_object.run)
        self.init_procedure_object.finished.connect(self._init_procedure_finished)
        self.init_procedure_object.finished.connect(self.thread_initialize.quit)
        self.show()

    @pyqtSlot()
    def _btn_go_clicked(self):
        # start thread
        self.btn_perform_actions.setEnabled(False)
        self.__logger.info("Launch Thread")
        self.thread_initialize.start()

    def _init_procedure_finished(self):
        self.btn_perform_actions.setEnabled(True)


class LongProcedureWorker(QObject):
    finished = pyqtSignal()

    def __init__(self, main_app: MainApp):
        super(LongProcedureWorker, self).__init__()
        self._main_app = main_app

    @pyqtSlot()
    def run(self):
        long_procedure()
        self.finished.emit()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setStyle('Fusion')
    ex = MainApp()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: added an update I made some time ago to handle multiple progress bars

Answer (score 5):

*EDIT 2019-mar-12: It seems to me that the answer is : it could probably be done, but requires a lots of effort in order to remember where which line comes from for the QTextEdit to behave as instended. Plus, since tdm writes to stderr by default, you would end up with catching all exceptions traces too.
That is why I'll mark my own answer as solved: I find it more elegant to achieve the same purpose : show in pyqt what is happenning.*

---

Here is my best shot to obtain something close to the intended behavior.
It does not exactly respond to the question, because I changed the GUI design.
So I won't vote it as solved. Moreover, this is done all in one single python file. I plan to further challenge this solution to see if it works with real python modules doing tqdm imports.

I patched the basic tqdm class in a very ugly way. The main trick is to :

- dynamically change the tqdm module structure by storing the original tqdm class into a new name: `tqdm.orignal_class = tqdm.tqdm`
- then inherit tqdm.original class `class TQDMPatch(tqdm.orignal_class):`
- implement the constructor in order to force the file stream + any parameters to whatever you want: `super(TQDMPatch, self).__init__(... change some params ...)`. I gave my TQDM class a custom `WriteStream()` that writes into a `Queue()`
- change the GUI strategy to intercept and redirect your custom tqdm stream to a separate Qt widget. My widget is making the assumption that all received prints contain `\r`(which TQDM seems to be doing).

It is working both as in single python file and with multiple separated modules. In the latter case, imports order at startup is critical.

Screenshots:

Before launching processing

[image: Before launching processing]

During processing

[image: During processing]

At end of processing

[image: At end of procesing]

---

Here is the code

### ALL-IN-ONE FILE

```
# coding=utf-8

import datetime
import logging
import sys
import time
from queue import Queue

from PyQt5.QtCore import pyqtSlot, pyqtSignal, QObject, QThread, Qt
from PyQt5.QtGui import QTextCursor, QFont
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QTextEdit, QWidget, QToolButton, QVBoxLayout, QApplication, QLineEdit


# DEFINITION NEEDED FIRST ...
class WriteStream(object):
    def __init__(self, q: Queue):
        self.queue = q

    def write(self, text):
        self.queue.put(text)

    def flush(self):
        pass


# prepare queue and streams
queue_tqdm = Queue()
write_stream_tqdm = WriteStream(queue_tqdm)

################## START TQDM patch procedure ##################
import tqdm

# save original class into module
tqdm.orignal_class = tqdm.tqdm


class TQDMPatch(tqdm.orignal_class):
    """
    Derive from original class
    """

    def __init__(self, iterable=None, desc=None, total=None, leave=True,
                 file=None, ncols=None, mininterval=0.1, maxinterval=10.0,
                 miniters=None, ascii=None, disable=False, unit='it',
                 unit_scale=False, dynamic_ncols=False, smoothing=0.3,
                 bar_format=None, initial=0, position=None, postfix=None,
                 unit_divisor=1000, gui=False, **kwargs):
        super(TQDMPatch, self).__init__(iterable, desc, total, leave,
                                        write_stream_tqdm,  # change any chosen file stream with our's
                                        80,  # change nb of columns (gui choice),
                                        mininterval, maxinterval,
                                        miniters, ascii, disable, unit,
                                        unit_scale, False, smoothing,
                                        bar_format, initial, position, postfix,
                                        unit_divisor, gui, **kwargs)
        print('TQDM Patch called') # check it works

    @classmethod
    def write(cls, s, file=None, end="\n", nolock=False):
        super(TQDMPatch, cls).write(s=s, file=file, end=end, nolock=nolock)

    # all other tqdm.orignal_class @classmethod methods may need to be redefined !


# I mainly used tqdm.auto in my modules, so use that for patch
# unsure if this will work with all possible tqdm import methods
# might not work for tqdm_gui !
import tqdm.auto as AUTO

# change original class with the patched one, the original still exists
AUTO.tqdm = TQDMPatch
################## END of TQDM patch ##################

# normal MCVE code
__is_setup_done = False


class MainApp(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        setup_logging(self.__class__.__name__)

        self.__logger = logging.getLogger(self.__class__.__name__)
        self.__logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

        # create stdout text queue
        self.queue_std_out = Queue()
        sys.stdout = WriteStream(self.queue_std_out)

        layout = QVBoxLayout()

        self.setMinimumWidth(500)

        self.btn_perform_actions = QToolButton(self)
        self.btn_perform_actions.setText('Launch long processing')
        self.btn_perform_actions.clicked.connect(self._btn_go_clicked)

        self.text_edit_std_out = StdOutTextEdit(self)
        self.text_edit_tqdm = StdTQDMTextEdit(self)

        self.thread_initialize = QThread()
        self.init_procedure_object = InitializationProcedures(self)

        # std out stream management
        # create console text read thread + receiver object
        self.thread_std_out_queue_listener = QThread()
        self.std_out_text_receiver = ThreadStdOutStreamTextQueueReceiver(self.queue_std_out)
        # connect receiver object to widget for text update
        self.std_out_text_receiver.queue_std_out_element_received_signal.connect(self.text_edit_std_out.append_text)
        # attach console text receiver to console text thread
        self.std_out_text_receiver.moveToThread(self.thread_std_out_queue_listener)
        # attach to start / stop methods
        self.thread_std_out_queue_listener.started.connect(self.std_out_text_receiver.run)
        self.thread_std_out_queue_listener.start()

        # NEW: TQDM stream management
        self.thread_tqdm_queue_listener = QThread()
        self.tqdm_text_receiver = ThreadTQDMStreamTextQueueReceiver(queue_tqdm)
        # connect receiver object to widget for text update
        self.tqdm_text_receiver.queue_tqdm_element_received_signal.connect(self.text_edit_tqdm.set_tqdm_text)
        # attach console text receiver to console text thread
        self.tqdm_text_receiver.moveToThread(self.thread_tqdm_queue_listener)
        # attach to start / stop methods
        self.thread_tqdm_queue_listener.started.connect(self.tqdm_text_receiver.run)
        self.thread_tqdm_queue_listener.start()

        layout.addWidget(self.btn_perform_actions)
        layout.addWidget(self.text_edit_std_out)
        layout.addWidget(self.text_edit_tqdm)
        self.setLayout(layout)
        self.show()

    @pyqtSlot()
    def _btn_go_clicked(self):
        # prepare thread for long operation
        self.init_procedure_object.moveToThread(self.thread_initialize)
        self.thread_initialize.started.connect(self.init_procedure_object.run)
        self.thread_initialize.finished.connect(self.init_procedure_object.finished)
        # start thread
        self.btn_perform_actions.setEnabled(False)
        self.thread_initialize.start()


class ThreadStdOutStreamTextQueueReceiver(QObject):
    queue_std_out_element_received_signal = pyqtSignal(str)

    def __init__(self, q: Queue, *args, **kwargs):
        QObject.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.queue = q

    @pyqtSlot()
    def run(self):
        self.queue_std_out_element_received_signal.emit('---> STD OUT Queue reception Started <---\n')
        while True:
            text = self.queue.get()
            self.queue_std_out_element_received_signal.emit(text)


# NEW: dedicated receiving object for TQDM
class ThreadTQDMStreamTextQueueReceiver(QObject):
    queue_tqdm_element_received_signal = pyqtSignal(str)

    def __init__(self, q: Queue, *args, **kwargs):
        QObject.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.queue = q

    @pyqtSlot()
    def run(self):
        self.queue_tqdm_element_received_signal.emit('\r---> TQDM Queue reception Started <---\n')
        while True:
            text = self.queue.get()
            self.queue_tqdm_element_received_signal.emit(text)


class StdOutTextEdit(QTextEdit):  # QTextEdit):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super(StdOutTextEdit, self).__init__()
        self.setParent(parent)
        self.setReadOnly(True)
        self.setLineWidth(50)
        self.setMinimumWidth(500)
        self.setFont(QFont('Consolas', 11))

    @pyqtSlot(str)
    def append_text(self, text: str):
        self.moveCursor(QTextCursor.End)
        self.insertPlainText(text)


class StdTQDMTextEdit(QLineEdit):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super(StdTQDMTextEdit, self).__init__()
        self.setParent(parent)
        self.setReadOnly(True)
        self.setEnabled(True)
        self.setMinimumWidth(500)
        self.setAlignment(Qt.AlignLeft | Qt.AlignVCenter)
        self.setClearButtonEnabled(True)
        self.setFont(QFont('Consolas', 11))

    @pyqtSlot(str)
    def set_tqdm_text(self, text: str):
        new_text = text
        if new_text.find('\r') >= 0:
            new_text = new_text.replace('\r', '').rstrip()
            if new_text:
                self.setText(new_text)
        else:
            # we suppose that all TQDM prints have \r
            # so drop the rest
            pass


def long_procedure():
    # emulate import of modules
    from tqdm.auto import tqdm

    setup_logging('long_procedure')
    __logger = logging.getLogger('long_procedure')
    __logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
    tqdm_obect = tqdm(range(10), unit_scale=True, dynamic_ncols=True)
    tqdm_obect.set_description("My progress bar description")
    for i in tqdm_obect:
        time.sleep(.1)
        __logger.info('foo {}'.format(i))


class InitializationProcedures(QObject):
    def __init__(self, main_app: MainApp):
        super(InitializationProcedures, self).__init__()
        self._main_app = main_app

    @pyqtSlot()
    def run(self):
        long_procedure()

    @pyqtSlot()
    def finished(self):
        print("Thread finished !")  # might call main window to do some stuff with buttons
        self._main_app.btn_perform_actions.setEnabled(True)


def setup_logging(log_prefix):
    global __is_setup_done

    if __is_setup_done:
        pass
    else:
        __log_file_name = "{}-{}_log_file.txt".format(log_prefix,
                                                      datetime.datetime.utcnow().isoformat().replace(":", "-"))

        __log_format = '%(asctime)s - %(name)-30s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s'
        __console_date_format = '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'
        __file_date_format = '%Y-%m-%d %H-%M-%S'

        root = logging.getLogger()
        root.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

        console_formatter = logging.Formatter(__log_format, __console_date_format)

        file_formatter = logging.Formatter(__log_format, __file_date_format)
        file_handler = logging.FileHandler(__log_file_name, mode='a', delay=True)

        file_handler.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
        file_handler.setFormatter(file_formatter)
        root.addHandler(file_handler)

        tqdm_handler = TqdmLoggingHandler()
        tqdm_handler.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
        tqdm_handler.setFormatter(console_formatter)
        root.addHandler(tqdm_handler)

        __is_setup_done = True


class TqdmLoggingHandler(logging.StreamHandler):
    def __init__(self):
        logging.StreamHandler.__init__(self)

    def emit(self, record):
        msg = self.format(record)
        tqdm.tqdm.write(msg)
        # from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38543506/change-logging-print-function-to-tqdm-write-so-logging-doesnt-interfere-wit/38739634#38739634
        self.flush()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setStyle('Fusion')
    ex = MainApp()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

---

### WITH PROPER SEPARATED MODULES

Same solution but with actual separated files.

- `MyPyQtGUI.py`, the program entry point
- `output_redirection_tools.py` the very first import that should be done during execution flow. Hosts all the magic.
- `config.py`, a config module hosting config elements
- `my_logging.py`, custom logging configuration
- `third_party_module_not_to_change.py`, sample version of some code I use but don't want to change.

**MyPyQtGUI.py**

It is important to note that the very first import of the project should be `import output_redirection_tools` since it does all the tqdm hack job.

```
# looks like an unused import, but it actually does the TQDM class trick to intercept prints
import output_redirection_tools # KEEP ME !!!

import logging
import sys

from PyQt5.QtCore import pyqtSlot, QObject, QThread, Qt
from PyQt5.QtGui import QTextCursor, QFont
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QTextEdit, QWidget, QToolButton, QVBoxLayout, QApplication, QLineEdit

from config import config_dict, STDOUT_WRITE_STREAM_CONFIG, TQDM_WRITE_STREAM_CONFIG, STREAM_CONFIG_KEY_QUEUE, \
    STREAM_CONFIG_KEY_QT_QUEUE_RECEIVER
from my_logging import setup_logging

import third_party_module_not_to_change

class MainApp(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        setup_logging(self.__class__.__name__)

        self.__logger = logging.getLogger(self.__class__.__name__)
        self.__logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

        self.queue_std_out = config_dict[STDOUT_WRITE_STREAM_CONFIG][STREAM_CONFIG_KEY_QUEUE]
        self.queue_tqdm = config_dict[TQDM_WRITE_STREAM_CONFIG][STREAM_CONFIG_KEY_QUEUE]

        layout = QVBoxLayout()

        self.setMinimumWidth(500)

        self.btn_perform_actions = QToolButton(self)
        self.btn_perform_actions.setText('Launch long processing')
        self.btn_perform_actions.clicked.connect(self._btn_go_clicked)

        self.text_edit_std_out = StdOutTextEdit(self)
        self.text_edit_tqdm = StdTQDMTextEdit(self)

        self.thread_initialize = QThread()
        self.init_procedure_object = LongProcedureWrapper(self)

        # std out stream management
        # create console text read thread + receiver object
        self.thread_std_out_queue_listener = QThread()
        self.std_out_text_receiver = config_dict[STDOUT_WRITE_STREAM_CONFIG][STREAM_CONFIG_KEY_QT_QUEUE_RECEIVER]
        # connect receiver object to widget for text update
        self.std_out_text_receiver.queue_std_out_element_received_signal.connect(self.text_edit_std_out.append_text)
        # attach console text receiver to console text thread
        self.std_out_text_receiver.moveToThread(self.thread_std_out_queue_listener)
        # attach to start / stop methods
        self.thread_std_out_queue_listener.started.connect(self.std_out_text_receiver.run)
        self.thread_std_out_queue_listener.start()

        # NEW: TQDM stream management
        self.thread_tqdm_queue_listener = QThread()
        self.tqdm_text_receiver = config_dict[TQDM_WRITE_STREAM_CONFIG][STREAM_CONFIG_KEY_QT_QUEUE_RECEIVER]
        # connect receiver object to widget for text update
        self.tqdm_text_receiver.queue_tqdm_element_received_signal.connect(self.text_edit_tqdm.set_tqdm_text)
        # attach console text receiver to console text thread
        self.tqdm_text_receiver.moveToThread(self.thread_tqdm_queue_listener)
        # attach to start / stop methods
        self.thread_tqdm_queue_listener.started.connect(self.tqdm_text_receiver.run)
        self.thread_tqdm_queue_listener.start()

        layout.addWidget(self.btn_perform_actions)
        layout.addWidget(self.text_edit_std_out)
        layout.addWidget(self.text_edit_tqdm)
        self.setLayout(layout)
        self.show()

    @pyqtSlot()
    def _btn_go_clicked(self):
        # prepare thread for long operation
        self.init_procedure_object.moveToThread(self.thread_initialize)
        self.thread_initialize.started.connect(self.init_procedure_object.run)
        # start thread
        self.btn_perform_actions.setEnabled(False)
        self.thread_initialize.start()


class StdOutTextEdit(QTextEdit):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super(StdOutTextEdit, self).__init__()
        self.setParent(parent)
        self.setReadOnly(True)
        self.setLineWidth(50)
        self.setMinimumWidth(500)
        self.setFont(QFont('Consolas', 11))

    @pyqtSlot(str)
    def append_text(self, text: str):
        self.moveCursor(QTextCursor.End)
        self.insertPlainText(text)


class StdTQDMTextEdit(QLineEdit):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super(StdTQDMTextEdit, self).__init__()
        self.setParent(parent)
        self.setReadOnly(True)
        self.setEnabled(True)
        self.setMinimumWidth(500)
        self.setAlignment(Qt.AlignLeft | Qt.AlignVCenter)
        self.setClearButtonEnabled(True)
        self.setFont(QFont('Consolas', 11))

    @pyqtSlot(str)
    def set_tqdm_text(self, text: str):
        new_text = text
        if new_text.find('\r') >= 0:
            new_text = new_text.replace('\r', '').rstrip()
            if new_text:
                self.setText(new_text)
        else:
            # we suppose that all TQDM prints have \r, so drop the rest
            pass


class LongProcedureWrapper(QObject):
    def __init__(self, main_app: MainApp):
        super(LongProcedureWrapper, self).__init__()
        self._main_app = main_app

    @pyqtSlot()
    def run(self):
        third_party_module_not_to_change.long_procedure()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setStyle('Fusion')
    ex = MainApp()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**my_logging.py**

```
import logging
import datetime
import tqdm

from config import config_dict, IS_SETUP_DONE


def setup_logging(log_prefix, force_debug_level=logging.DEBUG):

    root = logging.getLogger()
    root.setLevel(force_debug_level)

    if config_dict[IS_SETUP_DONE]:
        pass
    else:
        __log_file_name = "{}-{}_log_file.txt".format(log_prefix,
                                                      datetime.datetime.utcnow().isoformat().replace(":", "-"))

        __log_format = '%(asctime)s - %(name)-30s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s'
        __console_date_format = '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'
        __file_date_format = '%Y-%m-%d %H-%M-%S'

        console_formatter = logging.Formatter(__log_format, __console_date_format)

        file_formatter = logging.Formatter(__log_format, __file_date_format)
        file_handler = logging.FileHandler(__log_file_name, mode='a', delay=True)

        file_handler.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
        file_handler.setFormatter(file_formatter)
        root.addHandler(file_handler)

        tqdm_handler = TqdmLoggingHandler()
        tqdm_handler.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
        tqdm_handler.setFormatter(console_formatter)
        root.addHandler(tqdm_handler)

        config_dict[IS_SETUP_DONE] = True


class TqdmLoggingHandler(logging.StreamHandler):
    def __init__(self):
        logging.StreamHandler.__init__(self)

    def emit(self, record):
        msg = self.format(record)
        tqdm.tqdm.write(msg)
        self.flush()
```

**output_redirection_tools.py**

```
import sys
from queue import Queue

from PyQt5.QtCore import pyqtSlot, pyqtSignal, QObject

from config import config_dict, IS_STREAMS_REDIRECTION_SETUP_DONE, TQDM_WRITE_STREAM_CONFIG, STDOUT_WRITE_STREAM_CONFIG, \
    STREAM_CONFIG_KEY_QUEUE, STREAM_CONFIG_KEY_STREAM, STREAM_CONFIG_KEY_QT_QUEUE_RECEIVER


class QueueWriteStream(object):
    def __init__(self, q: Queue):
        self.queue = q

    def write(self, text):
        self.queue.put(text)

    def flush(self):
        pass


def perform_tqdm_default_out_stream_hack(tqdm_file_stream, tqdm_nb_columns=None):
    import tqdm
    # save original class into module
    tqdm.orignal_class = tqdm.tqdm

    class TQDMPatch(tqdm.orignal_class):
        """
        Derive from original class
        """

        def __init__(self, iterable=None, desc=None, total=None, leave=True,
                     file=None, ncols=None, mininterval=0.1, maxinterval=10.0,
                     miniters=None, ascii=None, disable=False, unit='it',
                     unit_scale=False, dynamic_ncols=False, smoothing=0.3,
                     bar_format=None, initial=0, position=None, postfix=None,
                     unit_divisor=1000, gui=False, **kwargs):
            super(TQDMPatch, self).__init__(iterable, desc, total, leave,
                                            tqdm_file_stream,  # change any chosen file stream with our's
                                            tqdm_nb_columns,  # change nb of columns (gui choice),
                                            mininterval, maxinterval,
                                            miniters, ascii, disable, unit,
                                            unit_scale,
                                            False,  # change param
                                            smoothing,
                                            bar_format, initial, position, postfix,
                                            unit_divisor, gui, **kwargs)
            print('TQDM Patch called')  # check it works

        @classmethod
        def write(cls, s, file=None, end="\n", nolock=False):
            super(TQDMPatch, cls).write(s=s, file=file, end=end, nolock=nolock)
            #tqdm.orignal_class.write(s=s, file=file, end=end, nolock=nolock)

        # all other tqdm.orignal_class @classmethod methods may need to be redefined !

    # # I mainly used tqdm.auto in my modules, so use that for patch
    # # unsure if this will work with all possible tqdm import methods
    # # might not work for tqdm_gui !
    import tqdm.auto as AUTO
    #
    # # change original class with the patched one, the original still exists
    AUTO.tqdm = TQDMPatch
    #tqdm.tqdm = TQDMPatch


def setup_streams_redirection(tqdm_nb_columns=None):
    if config_dict[IS_STREAMS_REDIRECTION_SETUP_DONE]:
        pass
    else:
        configure_tqdm_redirection(tqdm_nb_columns)
        configure_std_out_redirection()
        config_dict[IS_STREAMS_REDIRECTION_SETUP_DONE] = True


def configure_std_out_redirection():
    queue_std_out = Queue()
    config_dict[STDOUT_WRITE_STREAM_CONFIG] = {
        STREAM_CONFIG_KEY_QUEUE: queue_std_out,
        STREAM_CONFIG_KEY_STREAM: QueueWriteStream(queue_std_out),
        STREAM_CONFIG_KEY_QT_QUEUE_RECEIVER: StdOutTextQueueReceiver(q=queue_std_out)
    }
    perform_std_out_hack()


def perform_std_out_hack():
    sys.stdout = config_dict[STDOUT_WRITE_STREAM_CONFIG][STREAM_CONFIG_KEY_STREAM]


def configure_tqdm_redirection(tqdm_nb_columns=None):
    queue_tqdm = Queue()
    config_dict[TQDM_WRITE_STREAM_CONFIG] = {
        STREAM_CONFIG_KEY_QUEUE: queue_tqdm,
        STREAM_CONFIG_KEY_STREAM: QueueWriteStream(queue_tqdm),
        STREAM_CONFIG_KEY_QT_QUEUE_RECEIVER: TQDMTextQueueReceiver(q=queue_tqdm)
    }
    perform_tqdm_default_out_stream_hack(
        tqdm_file_stream=config_dict[TQDM_WRITE_STREAM_CONFIG][STREAM_CONFIG_KEY_STREAM],
        tqdm_nb_columns=tqdm_nb_columns)


class StdOutTextQueueReceiver(QObject):
    # we are forced to define 1 signal per class
    # see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50294652/how-to-create-pyqtsignals-dynamically
    queue_std_out_element_received_signal = pyqtSignal(str)

    def __init__(self, q: Queue, *args, **kwargs):
        QObject.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.queue = q

    @pyqtSlot()
    def run(self):
        self.queue_std_out_element_received_signal.emit('---> STD OUT Queue reception Started <---\n')
        while True:
            text = self.queue.get()
            self.queue_std_out_element_received_signal.emit(text)


class TQDMTextQueueReceiver(QObject):
    # we are forced to define 1 signal per class
    # see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50294652/how-to-create-pyqtsignals-dynamically
    queue_tqdm_element_received_signal = pyqtSignal(str)

    def __init__(self, q: Queue, *args, **kwargs):
        QObject.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.queue = q

    @pyqtSlot()
    def run(self):
        # we assume that all TQDM outputs start with \r, so use that to show stream reception is started
        self.queue_tqdm_element_received_signal.emit('\r---> TQDM Queue reception Started <---\n')
        while True:
            text = self.queue.get()
            self.queue_tqdm_element_received_signal.emit(text)


setup_streams_redirection()
```

**config.py**

```
IS_SETUP_DONE = 'is_setup_done'

TQDM_WRITE_STREAM_CONFIG = 'TQDM_WRITE_STREAM_CONFIG'
STDOUT_WRITE_STREAM_CONFIG = 'STDOUT_WRITE_STREAM_CONFIG'
IS_STREAMS_REDIRECTION_SETUP_DONE = 'IS_STREAMS_REDIRECTION_SETUP_DONE'

STREAM_CONFIG_KEY_QUEUE = 'queue'
STREAM_CONFIG_KEY_STREAM = 'write_stream'
STREAM_CONFIG_KEY_QT_QUEUE_RECEIVER = 'qt_queue_receiver'

default_config_dict = {
    IS_SETUP_DONE: False,
    IS_STREAMS_REDIRECTION_SETUP_DONE: False,
    TQDM_WRITE_STREAM_CONFIG: None,
    STDOUT_WRITE_STREAM_CONFIG: None,
}

config_dict = default_config_dict
```

**third_part_module_not_to_change.py**

represents the kind of code I use and don't want to / cannot change.

```
from tqdm.auto import tqdm
import logging
from my_logging import setup_logging
import time


def long_procedure():

    setup_logging('long_procedure')
    __logger = logging.getLogger('long_procedure')
    __logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
    tqdm_obect = tqdm(range(10), unit_scale=True, dynamic_ncols=True)
    tqdm_obect.set_description("My progress bar description")
    for i in tqdm_obect:
        time.sleep(.1)
        __logger.info('foo {}'.format(i))
```

Comment: Your answer is very far from what you said you wanted, but it seems more beautiful than what you wanted

Comment: To be honest, I wasn’t even sure this would work since I was unaware of how class names, class hierarchy and class methods resolution works inside python’s guts.

Comment: I discovered that the hack method has a name : monkey patching (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5626193/what-is-monkey-patching)